# Convert tensor of unknown shape to a SparseTensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a tensor of partially unknown shape and a mask -- a tensor of same shape filled with `1.0` or `0.0` -- and I want to convert it into a SparseTensor, considering only the items corresponding to `1.0` in the mask. So, I think I have to go with something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(23)

BATCH = 3
LENGTH = None

dense = tf.placeholder(shape=[BATCH, LENGTH], dtype=tf.float32, name='dense')
mask = tf.placeholder(shape=[BATCH, LENGTH], dtype=tf.float32, name='mask')
indices = tf.where(tf.equal(mask, 0.0))
values = tf.gather_nd(dense, indices)
```

At this point, I don't know how to proceed, since, both the way that I tried ended up in different errors, as follows. The first:

```
sparse = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, shape=tf.shape(dense))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for Tensor with dtype int32: 'Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)'
```

The second:

```
sparse = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, shape=dense.get_shape())
ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (3, ?)
```

The third:

```
sparse = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, shape=[BATCH, LENGTH])
TypeError: Expected int64, got None of type '_Message' instead.
```

Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: In your case, isn't the shape for SparseTensor just [BATCH,  LENGTH]?

Comment: @abhisheknaik96 tried. Added the third error which is what I get using the explicit `[BATCH, LENGTH]` list.

Comment: I see. May I ask how the LENGTH variable is going to be set anyway?

Comment: @abhisheknaik96 it is intended to be null, I put it in the code just to make it easier to possibly set it doing my tests.

Answer (score 0):

In my case type casting the shape as `shape=tf.cast(tf.shape(dense), tf.int64)` in your first approach resolved the mentioned error.